# Jquery Autocomplete+Mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, sql

I'm looking for a location that can show me how to do this.

I have two text fields, one is a name. The other is a zip. I'm searching businesses that might have more then one office in a state and wanted to use the zip to further narrow down the result. I want to use a Jquery auto complete that is also querying the Mysql DB with 3000 rows.

I'm not a big developer. Are there any URLS that someone could point me to or someone I could pay to do this for me over a few hours for the right person?

Thanks,

Comment: See http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure you could find a developer to do it for you, but this isn't the place to look.

MySQL allows you to do [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) on databases (3,000 lines is a small db, so efficiency definitely won't be a problem).  What is your server technology?  That'll make a big difference upon how you actually set the whole thing up.

As far as the autocomplete in jQuery, [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete) has an excellent autocomplete widget.

Comment: Thanks for the full text search link, very interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

This example may help point you in the right direction. Like others have suggested, it uses the jquery ui autocomplete:

[Using jQuery Autocomplete to Populate Another Autocomplete](http://www.jensbits.com/2010/05/29/using-jquery-autocomplete-to-populate-another-autocomplete-asp-net-coldfusion-and-php-examples/)

Or, if that's overkill, try this one:

[jQuery UI Autocomplete Widget with PHP and MySQL](http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think the other answers are great, but I also want to recommend [Better Autocomplete](https://github.com/betamos/Better-Autocomplete), a customizable jQuery plugin (still under active development) that I am currently maintaining.